# summation notation rules

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, power-series

I have a summation series as following:
$$\sum_{n=1}^N f(n)=-\sum_{n=1}^Ng(n)+\frac{X}{4}-\sum_{i=1}^3\bigg|\sum_{n=1}^N h_i(n)\bigg|^2$$
where $N$ is some known integer and $X$ is a constant.

**Question:**

Is there any way by which I can write $f(n)$ in terms of $g(n)$ and $h_i(n)$ i.e. I want to get rid of summation sign on LHS of equation.

**My attempt:**

Write last term as:
$$\bigg|\sum_{n=1}^N h_i(n)\bigg|^2=\sum_{n=1}^N h^*_i(n) \sum_{n=1}^N h_i(n)$$
so
$$\sum_{n=1}^N f(n)=-\sum_{n=1}^Ng(n)+\frac{X}{4}-\sum_{i=1}^3\bigg\{\sum_{n=1}^N h^*_i(n) \sum_{n=1}^N h_i(n) \bigg\}\\
\sum_{n=1}^N f(n)=\sum_{n=1}^N \bigg[-g(n)+\frac{X}{4}-\sum_{i=1}^3 \bigg\{h^*_i(n) \sum_{n=1}^N h_i(n)\bigg\}\bigg]\\
f(n)=\bigg[-g(n)+\frac{X}{4}-\sum_{i=1}^3 \bigg\{h^*_i(n) \sum_{n=1}^N h_i(n)\bigg\}\bigg]$$

I am not sure if I am doing it right or not. Also, $\frac{X}{4}$ factor was not depending on $n$.

Answer (score 1):

**No, there isn't:** You have an equation constraining the sum $f(1) + f(2) + \cdots + f(N)$ to some value that depends on the functions and constant on the RHS.  All you have is a constraint on the sum, which is not sufficient to obtain equations for the individual elements $f(i)$ (except in the trivial case where $N=1$).  A simple analogy to this would be if I told you that I have a total of $245 in my money box, and asked you to deduce the individual notes/coins that make up that sum (with no additional information other than the number of notes + coins).  Obviously that information would be insufficient to answer my question - you cannot deduce individual values solely from a constraint on their sum.

---

**Note:** For the above, I am taking you at your word that this equation holds true for some *particular* value of $N$ (i.e., that it is a single constraint).  If, on the other hand, you mean that this equation holds for all $N \in \mathbb{N}$ then that is actually a whole sequence of equations, and in that case you could get equations for each $f(i)$ via induction.